# Why aren't Marketing Cloud SDKs open source?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sdk

Why are these SDKs distributed as static/dynamic libs, and are not open source?

I expect this kind of SDK to contain no business logic, therefore there would be no reason to hide the implementation of whatever is inside them.

Making them open would be great for developers, as we'd be able to see what's being inserted in our code (are you hiding something?). It would also facilitate solving issues (like [this reported dependency conflict](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/211390/cant-use-marketing-cloud-sdk-for-android-with-google-play-services-11-8-0)).

The fact that the GitHub repos don't allow us to open issues to report bugs, suggest changes or fixes, and have a better channel of communicating directly with the devs at Salesforce.

Comment: Well, asking why software was written or released in a specific way is almost always impossible to answer for anyone besides the author. So this category of question usually is off topic. Now in reference to the Marketing Cloud SDKs that one point of view might actually be available...Bill Mote seems to monitor this space fairly regularly.

Comment: Trying to tweet him to get his attention, but my posts are failing to publish for some reason.